# php indent in web-mode with Emacs

Tags: emacs, php

I'm using Emacs web-mode and write a setting for it like this.

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))

(defun web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2) ;; html indent
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)    ;; css indent
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'web-mode-hook)
```

But indent of php code remain 8. (HTML indent is 2 as I expected)
Why does not change the offset indention of php?

Answer (score 1):

I set the value with `setq-default`

```
(setq-default web-mode-markup-indent-offset tab-width)
(setq-default web-mode-css-indent-offset tab-width)
(setq-default web-mode-code-indent-offset tab-width)
(setq-default web-mode-sql-indent-offset tab-width)
```